# How can I set default_url_options for Sidekiq workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, worker, sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq worker that is intended to perform social actions (e.g.: like pages on Facebook).  Part of this requires knowing the URL for the object being liked.

Fortunately, Rails 3 makes it easy to access app-specific routes by including `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in whatever class or module needs access to the path/url helper method.

The problem I'm running into is that my default url/port are not accessible from within my Sidekiq worker despite various attempts to define them in my `development.rb` or `production.rb`.

```
class Facebook::LikeRecipeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  sidekiq_options queue: :facebook

  def perform(recipe_id, user_id)
    recipe = Recipe.find(recipe_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)

    if user.facebook_token
      api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user.facebook_token)
      api.put_connections 'me', 'my_namespace:like', object: recipe_url(recipe)
    end
  end
end
```

When the `recipe_url` method is access, an `ArgumentError` is raised with the message:

> ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

I know that I can specify `default_url_options` for `ActionController` or `ActionMailer` in the environment-specific config files, e.g.:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

However, these (rightfully) appear to have no influence on my Sidekiq worker classes.  How should I go about defining `default_url_options` for these classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What we did was this:

In your config file(s) (e.g. config/application.rb, config/production.db, etc.), have a line that sets the default:

```
 routes.default_url_options = { host: 'www.example.org' }
```

Comment: Changing the accepted answer to yours since it's obviously working better for people.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found a potential solution to this, though it feels like a little bit of a hack.  I'm definitely open to better answers.

First, in my environment files (e.g.: `config/environments/development.rb`), I specify the `default_url_options` for my controllers:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

Then in my worker class, I define a `default_url_options` instance method there:

```
class Facebook::LikeRecipeWorker
  # ...

  private

  def default_url_options
    ActionController::Base.default_url_options
  end
end
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer since no other answers have been given.

Comment: I wish there was a better way. When an app can run in several environments -- multiple developers, staging, qa, beta server, etc -- this is an annoying config to have to manage. It would be so much better if Rails would just cache the last request attrs and make it accessible everywhere.